# why renderCamera is not call again

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using `DrawerNavigator` to navigate.

Why the renderCamera is not call again after first time?

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from "react-navigation";
import QRCodeScanner from "react-native-qrcode-scanner";
class QrCodeCamera extends Component {

      renderCamera() { //not run after 2nd time navigate to
         const isFocused = this.props.navigation.isFocused();

         if (!isFocused) {
             return null;
         } else if (isFocused) {
             return (
                <QRCodeScanner />
             )
         }

      render() {
         return (
           <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              {this.renderCamera()}
           </View>
     }
}

export default withNavigationFocus(QrCodeCamera);
```

---

I **solve** it by putting the pages into createStackNavigator instead of createDrawerNavigator.

Comment: Hello, are you using a tab or a drawer navigator?

Comment: DrawerNavigator